# How to Pause Circular Reveal Animation

Tags: java, android, material-design

I am using CircularRevealLibrary to make my header layout reveal. But what I want is to be able to stop the animation in half way. How to do this? Im using the following code.

```
int x = v.getRight(), y = v.getBottom(), startRadius = 0;
int endRadius = (int) Math.hypot(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());

SupportAnimator animator = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(v, x, y, startRadius, endRadius);
animator.start();
```

Im getting this

[image]

But I want to pause the animation in half way
[image]